# Perlin noise map color transition with uniform thickness

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, terrain, perlin-noise

I want to create a evenly sized zone at a specific height to transition between colors.
The issue i am having is that i cannot get this zone to stay even in size.[image]
Is there a way to achieve this?

I have tried

```
        if (noise >= .21f& noise < .213f)
                {

                    pixelColour = Color.Lerp(Color.blue, Color.yellow, Mathf.InverseLerp(.21f, .213f, noise));

                }
```

Comment: Youll want to use some cut-off values rather than invlerp if you want a hard border

Comment: What do you mean by cut-off values? Do you have a example?